# java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.8.3

Tags: illegalstateexception

When I am building the Spark 1.6 source code for Hadoop version 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 and Yarn with the sbt build and maven build i am getting below same error:

```
[error] (yarn/*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded.
IvyNode = org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.8.3
```

I have added maven depencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and also I have added below dependency in plugins.sbt file inside project folder

```
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson"  % "jackson-core-asl" % "1.8.3" % "test" intransitive()
```

and I tried adding as

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.codehaus.jackson"  % "jackson-core-asl" % "1.8.3" in plugins.sbt
```

But still error is not gone.

Please help on the same,
Thank you
Karim

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this is the reason... 
"All Codehaus services have now been terminated."